# Undefined function or method 'nanvar_base' in Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics

Somehow my Matlab does not has the function nanvar_base, needed to use the function ttest2 to calculate the t and p value of two sample data. How do I install that function? Is it missing to anyone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`ttest2`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/ttest2.html) is part of the statistics toolbox.

However, when I try to edit it, it does not show any calls to `nanvar_base`.

Did you perhaps try to edit it yourself, and in the process made a mistake? If this is not the case, try `edit ttest2` and see where it is located and show the line with the call to `nanvar_base`.

Comment: You're right, `ttest2` is part of the Statistics toolbox, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: this answer helped me to solve my problem, there was another toolbox (spm) that had a nanvar function that was conflicting with the original nanvar function from matlab. That function was calling a nanvar_base that didn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, the ttest2 function calling a nanvar function from SPM rather than the MATLAB statistics folder. A simple fix is going into 'change paths' in MATLAB and moving the SPM paths to the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 0):

This function isn't part of MATLAB or any of its toolboxes/add-ons. It must be custom functions. There is a function call `nanvar` however, in the Statistics toolbox and also in the Financial toolbox. Is this maybe the one you're after? If so, do you actually have the Statistics Toolbox and/or the Financial Toolbox?

Comment: I do have the Statistics Toolbox

Comment: Then, you can use `nanvar` provided you have a license for the toolbox, but as I said, there is no such thing as `nanvar_base`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is probably another toolbox (like SPM) getting in the way, with their own 'nanvar' function.
Move SPM to the bottom of the path definition list, or remove it completely. 
In general moving SPM have a lot of conflicting functions, so always make sure their path is at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when calling the function nanvar, and realised that there was a conflict with a function with the same name in the Fieldtrip toolbox (this Fieldtrip function calls nanvar_base). After removing the Fieldtrip/src folder from my paths, it worked fine.